# selectManyCheckbox into p:dataTable column

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, selectmanycheckbox

I can not correctly view the contents of a column with selectManyCheckbox in p:dataTable.

Here my .xhtml:

```
<h:form id="projAccess" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p:dataTable tableStyle="width:auto" id="i_dtb2"  var="p" value="#{comBean.l_uSrcRes}" paginator="true" rows="5" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10"
        paginatorPosition="bottom">

    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="User" />
            <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Asset" />
            <p:column colspan="6" headerText="Roles" />
            <p:column rowspan="2" colspan="2" headerText="Action" />
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column headerText="Project Manager"></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Project Manager Deputy"></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Business Analyst"></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Functional Analyst"></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Technical Analyst"></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Developer"></p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{p.usercd}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{p.asset}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column colspan="6">          
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" >
                <p:selectManyCheckbox columns="6"  value="#{p.rolesList}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{comBean.l_roles}" var="role" itemLabel="#{role}" itemValue="#{role}"  />
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>
        </h:panelGroup>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton action="#{comBean.m_updateAccess}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-pencil">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{p}" target="#{comBean.f_selectedUser}" />
                    <f:param name="area" value="project" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton action="#{ubean.m_deleteUser}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-trash">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{p}" target="#{comBean.f_selectedUser}" />
                    <f:param name="area" value="project" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

Here the result:

[image]

How can I adapt content to header columns?

Comment: I cannot see what is not correct here, please clarify your problem

Comment: The values in the columns (check + Project Manager ecc...) are not well matched with field name (Project Manager). Each value (check + name) must only belong to a column.

Comment: Then you most likely have something wrong with the columnGroup/and or the colspan on them.

Comment: It's probably but i don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `tableStyle="width:auto"` in your `p:dataTable`.
Removing this will align the checkboxes to its respective columns but you can notice that the columns are still a little bit misaligned.

To solve this, you can add `style="padding:0px;"` on your checkbox `p:column`.
Your code will look something like this.

```
<p:dataTable id="i_dtb2" var="p" value="#{comBean.l_uSrcRes}" paginator="true" rows="5" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10"
        paginatorPosition="bottom">

    // other codes

    <p:column colspan="6" style="padding:0px;">  
        // other codes
    </p:column>

    // other codes

</p:dataTable>
```

On another note, if your functional specification allows it, you can remove [Project Manager, Project Manager Deputy, etc] headers, since your are displaying them right next to the checkboxes.
You will have to remove `p:columnGroup` and set the `headerText` to their respective columns with "Roles" as `headerText` for your checkBox column.

Hope this helps.